# Using Apache 2 Licensed fonts in a Logo

Tags: fonts, logo, copyright, legal

This matter seems to be quite unclear since Apache License v2 is normally used for software. There are actually quite a few fonts that I find interesting and, I would like to use them in some company logos I'm designing. Reading the license, the confusion persists. Is it "allowed" or "legal" to use such a font, in its unmodified form (excluding color and size), in a commercial logo or company logo? If so, are there any requirements?

Comment: [This](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html) may provide some information.

Comment: As it seems you have found the answer to your own questions, please consider posting it as an answer instead of an edit to your question. It's clearer for later visitors with the same quandary. Thanks!

Comment: Removed it. reduce confusion. thanks for mentioning.

Comment: A digital typeface *is* software.

Comment: @SimonWhite Ahhh, ok. So it is considered software. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think section 2 sums it up fairly clearly (well, as clearly as licenses can be):

> 2. Grant of Copyright License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable copyright license to reproduce, prepare Derivative Works of, publicly display, publicly perform, sublicense, and distribute the Work and such Derivative Works in Source or Object form.

To me that reads as "it's open source, do with it as you please..."

Comment: Thanks! this was confusing me **6. Trademarks.** But i get now :)

Comment: @JoeDF 6. is about the Apache mark itself; it's irrelevant here. But you will still need to attribute etc. - don't forget the other rules in the licsense!