# Can I use an OFL or Apache font to produce a commercial product based around the font?

Tags: licensing, font-licensing

I'm interested in making some physical goods based around well known fonts that are released under the OFL license in order to sell them. For example, a block of wood in the shape of Lobster's letter "L" or digital CAD files showing how to print the "L" with a 3D printer.

Are these uses of the font permissible with OFL licensed fonts? What about the Apache license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for SIL OFL fonts - read this: [Open Font Licence FAQs](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#c26665c2).

Here's the quote

> Question: 1.1 Can I use the fonts for a book or other print publication, to create logos or other graphics or even to manufacture objects based on their outlines?
>
> Answer: Yes. You are very welcome to do so. Authors of fonts released under the OFL allow you to use their font software as such for any kind of design work. No additional license or permission is required, unlike with some other licenses. Some examples of these uses are: logos, posters, business cards, stationery, video titling, signage, t-shirts, personalised fabric, 3D-printed/laser-cut shapes, sculptures, rubber stamps, cookie cutters and lead type.

I assume the Apache fonts are similar but you should check the licences for the font.  With most free fonts there is usually a distinction between the normal use of a font, as opposed to redistributing the font. *Disclaimer:* I am no lawyer. If you want someone to decipher the Apache font licence (and you'll need one), then hire a lawyer.  However the answer to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39592/using-apache-2-licensed-fonts-in-a-logo) might provide an answer to that.